# Strategies to work with system of trigonometric inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, optimization, systems-of-equations

I'm trying solve this problem using matlab, anybody know good strategies to work with system of trigonometric inequalities such as

$ \left[\exp(-q_1*i)\cos^3(p_3)\sin(p_1)\sin(p_2)\sin(p_3)\right]\cdot a - \left[\exp(-q_2i)\exp(-q_3i)\cos(p_1)\cos(p_2)\cos^2(p_3)\sin(p_2)\sin^2(p_3) \right]\cdot b \neq 0,$

where $a$ and $b$ are complex variables and $q_{i}$ and $p_{i}$ are real variables. The real system (the least of them) have 18 inequalities and 8 variables, I need know if there is a set of values (8 real values) that makes true at least one of the inequalities. Maybe a good path is know how determine the minimum value of a expression of type

$\left[\exp(a_1i)\cos^3(a_2)\sin(a_3)\sin(a_4)\sin^2(a_5)\right]$,

or a bit more complex like

$\left[\exp(a_1i)\cos^3(a_2)\sin(a_3)\sin(a_4)\sin^2(a_5)\right] \cdot \left[\exp(-b_1i)\cos^2(b_2)\sin(b_3)\sin(b_4)\sin^3(b_5)\right].$

Then, some idea?

Comment: Being equal to zero is hard, so almost any values of the variables will make the expression nonzero.

Comment: If you take $a=b$, and $p_i = q_i = r$, your inequality reduces to $$0 \neq a e^{-2ir} \cos^3r \sin^3 r (e^{ir} - \cos r) = aie^{-2ir}\cos^3r\sin^4r$$ This is satisfied by any $a\neq 0$ and $r \neq n\pi/2$ (for integer $n$). But that's really over-thinking things. As @RossMillikan notes, *almost-any* values of the individual variables will make your expression non-zero.